# how to malloc for this structure

Tags: c, malloc

```
typedef struct testMsg_ {
    unsigned char opCode;
    unsigned int  Count;
    char    *macsStrList[MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN];
} testMsg_t;
```

Number of elements in macsStrList is m_Count.

I know following is not correct:

```
testMsg_t *pInput = (testMsg_t *) malloc(sizeof(testMsg_t) );
```

Comment: what is portProfileBulkMsg_t ?

Comment: and ... why do you have an array of `MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN` char pointers? Is that supposed to be a fixed-size char array, or a pointer to a dynamically-sized string?

Comment: Its s double dimensional array. I need an array of strings in C

Comment: @Useless: a list of MAC addresses perhaps? ... assumption based on the name.

Comment: yeah, but it's an array not a list, and it seems inside-out (there are `STR_LEN` pointers, but the length of each pointed string is unspecified)

Answer (score 3):

This **is** correct, given the structure you have done

> testMsg_t *pInput = (testMsg_t *) malloc(sizeof(testMsg_t) );

However you are probably confused to the meaning of `*arr[dimension]` -- which is an array length dimension of pointers to chars -- reading between the lines,

> > MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN

Is probably ment to the legth of the string representation of a mac address (say <20 bytes?)

However your struct gives you 20 char pointers, and the character pointers still have to be initializaed to point to valid memory.

```
testMsg_t *pInput = (testMsg_t *) malloc(sizeof(testMsg_t) );
pInput->macsStrList[0] = (char *) malloc( MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1 );
pInput->macsStrList[1] = (char *) malloc( MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1 );
pInput->macsStrList[2] = (char *) malloc( MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1 );
...
```

or redefine your struct to

```
typedef struct testMsg_ {
    unsigned char opCode;
    unsigned int  Count;
    char    macsStrList[NUMBER_OF_MAC_ADDRESSES][MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN];
} testMsg_t;
```

To avoid having to deal with multiple number of allocations.

**ADDITION**;

As per comments, given that the number of mac addresses are dynamically determined, you could also define the struct as;

```
typedef struct testMsg_ {
        unsigned char opCode;
        unsigned int  Count;
        char    macsStrList[1][MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN];
    } testMsg_t;
```

and then allocate it using

```
testMsg_t *pInput = (testMsg_t *) malloc(sizeof(testMsg_t) + (countOfMacsAddresses * MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN) );
```

That would have the added over a solution with pointers of that you could use `realloc` to resize the array dynamically if you needed to do that as well.....

Comment: I do not know the number of mac addresses in advance. So I cant have this in struct char    macsStrList[NUMBER_OF_MAC_ADDRESSES][MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN];

Comment: But can I have like this char macsStrList[1][MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN]; and later allocate more for mac strings?

Comment: In that case your structure is just wrong -- you need to have a linked list instead of a fixed size array.   In C struct are fixed size, so you need to manage the variability of the number of mac-addresses outside the struct -- if you were to implement it in C++ you could use something like Vector or Dequeu to help, but that is not available in C

Comment: what about this - testMsg_t *pInput = (testMsg_t *) malloc( sizeof(testMsg_t) + m_Count*( MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1)); ?

Comment: That would allocated the memory, however your structure still needs to have the pointers of `macsStrList`initialized -- but with some extra code that is doable -- but not necessarily clean or recommended unless you know exactly what you are doing

Comment: **Actually,** if you define the struct with  `char macsStrList[1][MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1];` and then do the allocation as you suggest `malloc( sizeof(testMsg_t) + m_Count*( MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1));`, then there are no pointers to initialize and it may just all work as you want it.....

Comment: How about?  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_Count; i++)
        {
        pInput->macsStrList[i] = (char *) malloc( MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1 );
        }

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is maybe (ok, Soren got in first, but I'll show a way to allocate a single contiguous chunk):

```
/* assuming we only need macStrList[0] ... [Count-1] */
struct testMsg
{
    unsigned char opCode;
    unsigned int  Count;
    char *macsStrList[];
};

struct testMsg *allocate_testMsg(int count)
{
    char *string_storage;
    struct testMsg *msg;

    size_t size = sizeof(struct testMsg)   /* base object */
                + (count * sizeof(char *)) /* char* array */
                + (count * (MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1)) /* char storage */
                ;

    msg = malloc(size);
    msg->Count = count;
    string_storage = (char *)&(msg->macStrList[count]);

    /* note msg->macStrList points to UNINITIALIZED but allocated storage.
       it might be sensible to zero-fill string_storage, depending on how you'll
       initialize it
    */
    for (count=0; count < msg->Count;
         ++count, string_storage += (MAC_ADDR_STR_LEN+1))
    {
        msg->macStrList[count] = string_storage;
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. You allocate a pointer to a `testMsg_t` which is an alias for `struct testMsg_`. However you need to initialize this object yourself.

(And you don't need to cast the allocated pointer in C).